# CickListener paso de un String a otra Activity Android

Tags: android

Tengo un for recorrer los datos de un Json y mostralos en un ListView. Hasta acá, todo bien.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada elemento de lista sea clickeable y envíe a otro activity uno de los parámetros recibidos del son. En este caso "LINK_FICHA" que es un URL.

El tema es que el método de onItemClick necesita un int no se puede con un String tipo URL

Me pueden ayudar a encontrar una solución?

```html
               for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

                    ModelListView modelListView = new ModelListView();
                    JSONObject dataobj = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                    modelListView.setPARLID(dataobj.getInt("PARLID"));
                    modelListView.setLINK_FICHA(dataobj.getString("LINK_FICHA"));
                    modelListView.setNOMBRE(dataobj.getString("NOMBRE"));
                    modelListView.setEMAIL(dataobj.getString("EMAIL"));
                    modelListViewArrayList.add(modelListView);
                    String link = dataobj.getString("LINK_FICHA");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "url: "+link,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    /* click link */
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int link, long l) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, webVSenadores.class);
                            intent.putExtra("url",link);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    /* click link end */
                }
```

Comment: El int position permite un Entero (la posición del item list), pero lo que necesito en la variable link, que es un string (una url), El tema es que no como recibir esa variable para el intent.putExtra

Comment: Ya probé eso, no me da ningún error, lo que hace es que solo toma la URL del último elemento de la lista y la repite, pero cada elemento tiene una lista distinta. Por lo que leo, estoy usando un método incorrecto, Tienes alguna sugerencia de qué podría utilizar?

Comment: Claro, entonces intenta sacar el codigo del listView.setOnItemClickListener ... del del ciclo `for` e intenta obtener el item con el `position` poniendo este codigo en el `onItemClick`: `JSONObject dataobj = obj.getJSONObject(position);` y luego, `String link = dataobj.getString("LINK_FICHA");`. Ten en cuenta que `obj` debe ser final.  Otra manera es hacer que esa data que obtinenes, sea parte del item o lista que maneja el adapter. Si no entiendes algo dejame saber

Comment: @EdgardoBriones el listener no debe estar definido dentro del bucle.Si tienes un getter getLINK_FICHA() puede obtener el valor de la url que almacenaste , mediante la posición del elemento en la lista, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente debes obtener los datos para agrearlos a tu lista `ModelListView`, posteriormente define el listener, pero este al ser llamado ya tendras valores en la lista  `ModelListView`, solo tienes que obtener el valor correcto de la url mediante `position`.

Suponiendo que tienes un getter llamado `getLINK_FICHA()` , puedes obtener de esta forma la url que será enviada mediante el `Intent`:

:

```
               for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

                    ModelListView modelListView = new ModelListView();
                    JSONObject dataobj = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                    modelListView.setPARLID(dataobj.getInt("PARLID"));
                    modelListView.setLINK_FICHA(dataobj.getString("LINK_FICHA"));
                    modelListView.setNOMBRE(dataobj.getString("NOMBRE"));
                    modelListView.setEMAIL(dataobj.getString("EMAIL"));
                    modelListViewArrayList.add(modelListView);
                    String link = dataobj.getString("LINK_FICHA");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "url: "+link,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


                    /* click link */
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int link, long position) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, webVSenadores.class);

                            //*Obtiene URL
                            link = modelListView.get(position).getLINK_FICHA();

                            intent.putExtra("url",link);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    /* click link end */
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys. Me sirvió perfecto. La línea *link = modelListView.get(position).getLINK_FICHA();* Hizo el cambio cambio y el *int* lleva el *position* no el link